# Highlight dynamically generated contents when reach anchor

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a table of contents, that contains all the h2 tags of a page. I have created this with jQuery like so:

```
<div class="post">
<h2>Some title</h2>
<p>texttexttext<br></p><p>texttexttext<br></p><p>texttexttext<br></p>
<h2>Some title2</h2>
<p>texttexttext<br></p><p>texttexttext<br></p><p>texttexttext<br></p>
<h2>Some other title</h2>
<p>texttexttext<br></p>

<div class='post_navigation'>Navigation</div>
</div>
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
var alltags= new Array();

            jQuery('.post h2').each(function(){
                alltags.push(jQuery(this).text());
                var content=jQuery(this).text();
                jQuery('.post_navigation').append('<div class=\'post_navigation_div\'>'+content+'</div>');  
            });
</script>
```

this creates a list of all the h2 tags from .post to div with class post_navigation_div.

Then I wanted to make it sticky, so that when user scrolls past it it will change it's position:

```
var targetOffset = jQuery('.post_navigation').offset().top;
            jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
                if ( jQuery(this).scrollTop() > targetOffset ) {   
                    jQuery('.post_navigation').css({'position':'fixed','top':'32px'});
                } else {
                  jQuery('.post_navigation').css({'position':'initial'});
                }
            });
```

this also works. Now i wanted to add a click functionality, so when the user clicks on any of the elements of that content table to scroll to its h2 tag, so:

```
jQuery('.post_navigation div').on('click', function(){
                        var textt=(jQuery(this).text());
                        jQuery('.post h2').each(function(){
                            if(jQuery(this).text()==textt){
                                jQuery('html, body').animate({
                                    scrollTop: jQuery(this).offset().top
                                }, 1000);
                            }       
                        });
            });
```

this also works.

And where is my question, how can I add a code, that when user scrolls after specific h2 element, to highlight to element of the table, so we know which h2 we are reading currently?
I have tried with something like so:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
            jQuery('.post h2').each(function(){
                var position=jQuery(this).offset().top;
                var texttt=jQuery(this).text();
                if(jQuery(window).scrollTop()>position){


console.log('reached '+texttt);
                }
                
            });
        });
```

but the issue is that when we go past h2 (first occurrence) then we reach second we still get the position and content of first occurrence, since browser is past that scroll.

EDIT:Added more code for minimal required for example.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Edited with more HTML for example